# Why does clicking a drag handle NOT steal away text focus?

Tags: jquery-ui, browser

I have a div with some text at http://jsfiddle.net/MuCeD/2/. If I double-click the word "sample" in the div it becomes highlighted and if I then click anywhere else on the page the text becomes un-highlighted - *except* if I click on the blue drag handle of the second box. Then "sampled" remains highlighted.

If you remove the handle specification, as below,

```
$('#box').draggable();
```

so you can drag from anywhere on the left box, then you can click anywhere in that box without losing the text focus.

Does anyone understand what's going on here?  What does the drag handle do to keep from stealing the focus?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jQuery UI draggable` cancels its `mousedown` event. This is why it doesn't receive focus and thus doesn't steal other elements' focus. You can use the following example outside of the draggable context.

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Some link</a>
<a class="not-focusable" href="#">No focus</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.not-focusable').mousedown(function (event) {
    return false;
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mr63/2/)

Comment: Yes! That works!  Thank you.  But there are still a couple of strange things about this situation that I'd like to try to understand before moving on.  If instead of return false; in your jsfiddle you put event.stopPropagation() the no-focus link takes the focus. You would think that stopPropagation() would have the same effect as return false.  Also, if you replace mousedown with click then neither return false nor stopPropagation will prevent the focus from being stolen. Do you have any idea what's going on there?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Steve No stopping the propagation does not cancel the event. It just prevents it from propagating to other DOM elements. preventDefault() does the same as returning false.